# textarea con tinymce que guarda caracteres extraños

Tags: mysql, tinymce

Tengo un textarea, al que le aplico un tinymce y termino almacenando el contenido en la base de datos. Todo perfecto: ahora veo que de golpe me almacena un caracter "rn" que no se de donde lo sacó:

```
asdasdasdasd

rn
asdasdasd

rn
asdasdasd
```

teoricamente es despues del retorno de carro...
lo extraño que uso la misma estructura en otra parte del sitio y no lo hace:

```
<p>asdasdasdasd</p>rn<p>asdasdasd</p>rn<p>asdasdasd</p>
```

asi esta guardado el registro en la base de datos... 
que podrá ser ?

estoy viendo que la unica diferencia con la parte donde guardo y no pasa nada es que en donde me incrusta esos "rn" hago un real_escape_string

```
  if($_POST['texto']!='') {
        $sTexto = strip_tags(stripslashes($mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['texto'])),$allowedTags);
    } else {
        $sTexto = "";
    }
```

será eso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que esté relacionado con los saltos de línea, prueba añadiendo:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        remove_linebreaks : false
});
```

Aquí puedes ver [más detalles](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:remove_linebreaks).